# How do I permanently delete a guest from a recurring Google Calendar event?

Tags: google-calendar

How do I permanently delete a guest from a recurring Google Calendar event?

The calendar does not ask if I want this to apply to only this event, or to future events as well like it does when changing the event times etc. So far, I have been updating each recurring event one by one, which is a huge hassle, since there is no end date.

Answer (score 7):

It looks like there's a bug that prevents you from removing a guest from a recurring event: https://support.google.com/calendar/thread/8260644

A way around this is to change the event to non-recurring, apply the changes (i.e., remove the guest and save), and change it back to recurring.

The second, and best, solution is for all of us to stop using Google's crap that has come to rule our lives instead of making them better as originally promised.

Comment: Ridiculous bug! Especially with this being 2.5 years later!

Answer (score 1):

You can actually edit out guests you want to remove, but you can only do that in the original calendar hold where you invited each guest, even if it's a recurring meeting. When you hover your pointer over the guest's name, the X does show up at the top right corner of the name and you can uninvite them by clicking on it. After that, they do not show on any of the subsequent meetings.

Answer (score 0):

One can successfully remove guest/guests from current, all, or forward. Select the meeting, then activate the edit mode via the pencil icon, mouse over the particular guest in question, there will be an x to the right of the person icon, delete the contact. One will not be asked to apply the current, all, or forward till you save the meeting. It will then be treated like when editing other portions of the meeting , ie time of meeting. When saving meeting a dialog box will appear to ask the application of the change.

Comment: This does not work: after you save, guests appear again on the event. This appears to be a bug (https://support.google.com/calendar/thread/8260644).